# pointer of class conversion(kinda copy) constructor to class

Tags: c++, pointers, copy-constructor, implicit-conversion

recently i got a piece of code from an external company which seems a bit odd. So my question is: Can somebody explain me the good and bad points of the following code design?

There is a

```
class A
{
  double val[2]; // actually within the original class there are: 
  // an int, two std::string,a boost::any(for a double and double*)
  // and a boost::shared_array<int>
  public:
  A(double value1, double value2)
  { 
    val[0] = value1;
    val[1] = value2;
  }
  // with normal constructor stuff here, but also
  A(A* const& a) // a pointer-to-object "copy"-constructor?!
  {
    memcpy(this->val, a->val, sizeof(double) * 2 ); 
    // no delete here either...
  }
}
```

Its used in a std::map like (not a pointer map!)

```
typedef std::map<std::string, A> aMap;
aMap mapOfA;
```

And then i find alot of these little gems everywhere in the code:

```
mapOfA.insert(std::make_pair("elite", new A(1.337)));
```

Take special note of that "new" before A! As far as i know, the keyword "new" allocates memory in the heap, which has to be removed with delete again(except for boost pointers and similar), i hope its still correct nowadays. ;)

So the code creates an object on the heap, passes it by pointer to that special pointer-conversion-copy-constructor which in turn passes itself by value to std::make_pair, because the map want to store the whole object not a pointer. Am i understanding this right so far? Out of curiosity i commented that "copy"-constructor and it gave as i expected a compiler error on every little gem (conversion from A* to non-scalar type A requested).

Given it is compiled with a GCC 4.1.2 is there any mechanism involved i dont know that makes this actually usefull? In my opinion its just really bad practice! Not only is it slow but also leaks memory alot, isnt it?

### Edit:

I change to array of double because the ppl where commenting to much about that memcpy feature which is actually okay, because its actually an boost::shared_array i just simplified for example purpose.

Comment: Yup, looks pretty awful.

Comment: Are the `new`ed objects deleted anywhere?

I would say usually stick to `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` depending on what is available. If none of these are available, they should be made available. Maybe not C++11 but definitely boost.

Comment: Agreed. Someone does not know how to code C++.

Comment: Are you sure it is `memcopy` and not `memcpy`?

Comment: there not a single delete within the whole library! I assume he thought that these std::containers are like smart_pointer taking care of their pointer (which even didnt got saved within the containers)

Comment: no its ofc memcpy, just a typo on my side

Comment: I just threw up in my mouth a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given it is compiled with a GCC 4.1.2 is there any mechanism involved i dont know that makes this actually usefull?

No. It's simply bad code.
You could clean it up through (you should probably start with removing the `A(A* const& a)` code).

> In my opinion its just really bad practice!

It allocates/leaks an element with each element it generates.
It also uses memcpy (apparently instead of assignment?).

> Not only is it slow but also leaks memory alot, isnt it?

Yes.

If I were to guess someone tried to implement a move constructor when initializing from a pointer, and made an incomplete, horrible mess out of it (probably before C++11?). That's just a guess though.

Comment: the memcpy was just to demonstrate that it actually internally allocates a double* and moves that around a bit... thanks for your input!

Comment: Oh ... ok; Anyway, if you _have_ to use that code, remove all the bogux pointer use and allocations first.

Comment: yep i ll change the code as @mikeSeymoure is describing it. i hope no more "gems" will be found there :-D

Answer (score 1):

Yuck! Why not drop the `memcpy` and simply use:

```
val = a->val;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct, and this code is insane. The author apparently doesn't understand C++ memory management, or even basic concepts like assignment; the `memcpy` is a weird obfuscation of `val = a->val;`

If I had to guess, I'd say the author had the misapprehension that class objects must be created with `new` (as they are in other popular languages), and added the freaky constructor to fix the ensuing compile error.

The correct fix is to probably to remove `new`:

```
mapOfA.insert(std::make_pair("elite", A(1.337)));
```

or just `1.337`, if the conversion from `double` is supposed to be implicit.

Comment: the memcpy was just to demonstrate that it actually internally allocates a double* and moves that around a bit... i edited the post. thanks alot for you input. i am actually working on it like you said!